# How to add the Document Viewer plugin phonegap

Tags: javascript, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, documentviewer

Can you help me to use the documentviewer correctly.

ref: https://github.com/sitewaerts/cordova-plugin-document-viewer

```
cordova.plugins.SitewaertsDocumentViewer.canViewDocument(
        url, contentType, options, onPossible, onMissingApp, onImpossible, onError);
```

I am using the below values and it is throwing `"Missing Command Error"` in windows broswer and has "no effect" on iOS.

```
cordova.plugins.SitewaertsDocumentViewer.canViewDocument(
    'mylocal.pdf', 'application/pdf', '', onPossible, onMissingApp, onImpossible, onError);
```

I need to use this for android. ios and windows.

Comment: I think everyone has this issue even 7 months later, wherever I look it's this exact same error and no solutions